# Google Fit App not showing path of workout uploaded using Rest API

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-api

I am trying to create a python app to upload workout data to be stored in google fit.

I am trying to get the map to show the path of my run. I have uploaded a dataset using com.google.location.sample which includes lat, lon, accuracy and elevation. I know that the data is being stored since running a "get" dataset returns the values I entered. I also know that the GPS points are registering because I get a map of the area where the session happened but there is no "path" of the actual run. I also know that all the points are being received since I have run this path a few times but different distances each time and the map zooms in/out based on how far I go.

[Screenshot Google Fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBgzp.png)

This is a sample of what I get. Is there some way to get the rest API to register and show the actual path as well as a graph for elevation? My code can be seen here:

https://github.com/omriasta/ifitsync

And here is a "GET" of the dataset from the google fit api:

https://gist.github.com/omriasta/e1d8c85677092ed89a25126e4b334e41

Does anyone know why the Google Fit App will not display a map with the path for this dataset?

Comment: You should format your question and give it some structure. The easier to read and understand, the easier to help :-)

Comment: Hope, this makes it a bit clearer...Not 100% sure I understand how else to "structure" it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through Trial and error it appears that the path will not be drawn unless the activity type is Running (integer 8). It appears that Treadmill Runs will not display the map even if they have location samples.